# Get the all the children from a Sitecore item in a parent-child relation

Tags: sitecore

The following code should return all the children and sub-children in a list, but it's not keeping the ordering of parent-child relation. It returns all the parent items first, and then all the child items.

Is it possible somehow to keep the items in order, and get them in a list in the same order as they are in Sitecore?

`MainItem` contains the items in the parent-child relation:

```csharp
Item mainItem= Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Settings.GetSetting("MainItem"));
mainItem.Axes.GetDescendants().ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add items to a list recursively:

```csharp
public void AppendItems(List<Item> itemList, Item item)
{
    foreach(Item childItem in item.Children)
    {
        itemList.Add(childItem);
        AppendItems(itemList, childItem);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```csharp
var list = new List<Item>();
list.Add(rootItem);
AppendItems(list, rootItem);
```